# Objectify does not fetch by String ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a datastore kind in which the ID field is String

```
ofy().load().type( Scores.class ).id( playerName ).now();
```

This fetches null. I have confirmed the entity with the given playername exists.
This does not happen to another Kind whose ID is long.

Code for Scores class

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;

@Entity
public class Scores
{
    @Parent
    public Key<RankerRoot> parentKey;
    @Id
    public String  playerName;
    public int value;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the code of your Scores Class? For the moment you can try doing `plarName.trim()`. I had some trouble with String format one year ago with an app.

Comment: Can you also see that the entity with key name `playerName` exists in Datastore (using the datastore viewer) and that it doesn't have an ancestor?

Comment: @tx802 Bang on ! It has an ancestor. I should have seen it coming. Let me try adding the ancestor() in the statement.

Comment: @Pintouch update the question with the code.

Comment: Now .id() does not work with .ancestor()

Comment: You can create the key separately with `Key<Scores> key = Key.create(parentKey, Scores.class, playerName)`, then call `ofy().load().key(key).now()` - does that work?

Comment: @tx802 Works ! Thank you. I should note down these syntax. Can you put this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure you are giving Objectify enough information to construct the entity's Key.  So, if the entity has an `ancestor`, the ID/Name alone will be insufficient.

If your entity has an ancestor, you can construct the Key and then load the entity by Key, like this:

```
Key<Scores> scoreKey = Key.create(parentKey, Scores.class, playerName);
ofy().load().key(scoreKey).now();
```